# Find range of $f(x)=\sqrt {2\{x\} -\{x\}^2} -\frac 34$

Tags: functions

> here {} implies fractional part function

Evaluating $2\{x\}-\{x\}^2\ge 0$

$$\{x\} \in [0,2]$$

Which is weird since $\{x\}\in [0,1)$ is a known range.

Basically I don’t know what to do here, and this was just my attempt

Ans is $[0,\frac 12]$

Comment: $t\le 2$ is true for any $2t-t^2\ge0,t\ge0$ . However if $t$ has a specific range in itself, you generally consider the ranges that overlap with each other

Comment: $$-\frac34\le f(x)<\frac14$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer can't be $[0, 1/2]$ because $f(0) = -3/4$ and $\lim_{x \to 1^-}f(x) = 1/4$. (You showed that the expression under the radical is never negative, which is certainly good to know.)

Indeed, we can show that the range is $[-3/4, 1/4)$ as follows. First, $\{x\}$ has range $[0, 1)$. Second, $\sqrt{2x - x^2}$ has range $[0, 1)$ on $[0, 1)$. Finally, $x - \frac34$ has range $[-3/4, 1/4)$ on $[0, 1)$. Composing these three functions will give you your result.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to determine  $f\bigl([0,1)\bigr)$. This can be done using the basic properties of inequalities:

Rewrite $f(x)$ as $\sqrt{1-(x-1)^2\strut}-\frac 34$ and note that $-1\le x-1<0$, so $0\le 1-(x-1)^2<1$, and ultimately:
$$-\frac34\le f(x)<\frac14.$$

Answer (score 0):

$\left[0,\frac12\right]$ is wrong

The fractional part ranges in $[0,1)$  subtract $\frac34$ and you have the result I gave in my comment: $$\left[-\frac34,\frac14\right)$$

[image]